# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString') in react testing library

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-testing-library

I am having this error [undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18EiY.png). I'm trying to mock the Axios but it says that "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')".

This is the code that I wanted to test from jsx file. [source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAbru.png)

I tried this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4sL6.png) and use this [mockImplementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SmOX.png) but I think I am lacking in my codes.

Thank you in advance and sorry if this was a redundant question.

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example instead of screenshots

Comment: Sorry for not using Minimal, Reproducible Example into my question, but this problem has been resolved. Thank you so much :)